# How to exclude query string with specific parameters from .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a Wordpress site and I am discarding query strings with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The above rules work fine, but I want to exclude some URLs with specific parameters in the query string. I have tried to insert the following rules between the two rules above, but I am apparently missing something and the exclusion doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/?post_type=project

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/?post_type=project&p=14507&et_fb=1&PageSpeed=off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?post_type=project

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?post_type=project$
```

My goal is to exclude URLs if they contain some or all of the parameters:

```
post_type=project

et_fb=1

PageSpeed=off
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule right below `RewriteEngine On` line (and above front controller WP rule):

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)post_type=project(?:&|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)et_fb=1(?:&|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)PageSpeed=off(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L,NE]

# more rule below this line
```

I am using 3 separate `RewriteCond` to be able to match these query parameters anywhere in query string (note use of `OR` clause).

Comment: @Yavor: Did this work out?